# Python push files to Github remote repo without local working directory

Tags: python, github, github-api

I am working on a Python based web application for collaborative xml/document editing, and one requirement from the client is that users should be able to push the files they created (and saved on the server) directly to a Github remote repo, without the need of ever creating a local clone on the server (i.e., no local working directory or tracking of any sort). In GUI terms, this would correspond to going to Github website and manually add the file to the remote repo by clicking the "Upload files" or "create new file" button, or simply edit the existing file on the remote repo on the Github website and then commit the change inside the web browser. I wonder is this functionality even possible to achieve either using some Python Github modules or writing some code from scratch using the Github API or something?

Comment: What is the problem with having local users install and configure Git?

Comment: the problem seems to be that the users of this web app is expected to be not technologically oriented and the purpose is to save them from going through the trouble of managing their local git account. (and yet take advantage of the git tracking on the remote repo by the project management)

Comment: `and yet take advantage of the git tracking on the remote repo` ... they can't really do that without having Git configured locally.  I would say either download Git, or just use upload from GitHub.

Comment: thanks! yeah I guess by that they just mean they can keep track of who edited what and when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can create files via the API and if the user has their own GitHub account, you can upload it as them.

Let's use github3.py as an example of how to do this:

```
import github3

gh = github3.login(username='foo', password='bar')
repository = gh.repository('organization-name', 'repository-name')
for file_info in files_to_upload:
    with open(file_info, 'rb') as fd:
        contents = fd.read()
    repository.create_file(
        path=file_info,
        message='Start tracking {!r}'.format(file_info),
        content=contents,
    )
```

You will want to check that it returns an object you'd expect to verify the file was successfully uploaded. You can also specify `committer` and `author` dictionaries so you could attribute the commit to your service so people aren't under the assumption that the person authored it on a local git set-up.

Comment: a quick follow-up question(still under the no local working directory assumption): what if the file already exists on the remote repo and I just want to update it with a modified file of the same name? (e.g., equivalent to on the Github website, upload a modified version of a file already existing on the remote)

Comment: @zangsir follow-up questions should be asked as new questions. Alternatively you can discover this for yourself by reading github3.py's documentation.

Comment: sorry I'll just ask a new question