# Python update files on Github remote repo without local working directory

Tags: python, github, github-api

This is a follow-up question to the question on pushing to remote repo without local working directory([Python push files to Github remote repo without local working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737192/python-push-files-to-github-remote-repo-without-local-working-directory/39770084?noredirect=1#comment67866611_39770084)). I wonder what if the file already exists on the remote repo and I just want to update it with a modified file of the same name? (e.g., equivalent to on the Github website, upload a modified version of a file already existing on the remote)

Edit: We've come up with a solution:

```
contents_object = repository.contents(file_path)
push_status = contents_object.update("test_message",contents)
```

However, while this runs successfully on one machine, it threw an error on another machine (specifically, the first line will get an AttributeError). Is this because of potentially different versions of github3?

Comment: Are you using some package to communicate with their API? The answer from your previous question uses github3. Have you looked at their documentation?

Comment: sorry, I am using github3, as the original post's answer suggested. I did look at the documentation but it wasn't immediately obvious which method would require having a local working directory or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear that under github3 version 0.9.6, which as of this time is what you will get with `pip install github3.py`(https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#installation), this will work(doing the update to the remote repo without any local working directory):

```
def update_to_git(username,password,path,account,repo,message):
    files_to_upload = [path]
    gh = github3.login(username=username, password=password)
    repository = gh.repository(account, repo)
    for file_info in files_to_upload:
        with open(file_info, 'rb') as fd:
            contents = fd.read()
        contents_object = repository.contents(file_info)
        contents_object.update(message,contents)
```

However, if you have github3 version 1.0.0a4, this will not work. Specifically, you will get an `AttributeError` for the `contents_object = repository.contents(file_info)` line, possibly due to the changes in the implementation in github3.

Comment: In v1.0.0a4, `Repository.contents()` has been split into `Repository.directory_contents()` and `Repository.file_contents()`.