# Create/Update .json file to GitHub Private Repository without making local working directory or cloning repo using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, git, github

I am having a GitHub Private Repository which has 3 .json files on its parent directory.
Suppose the three json files are:

```
1.json
2.json
3.json
```

**I am trying to write a function through which I can just push any one of the .json file through the python function with contents and it makes a commit and push the changes.**

I tried using solution from this but it seems outdated or unsupported: [Python update files on Github remote repo without local working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307982/python-update-files-on-github-remote-repo-without-local-working-directory)

Function should be liked this:

```
def update_file_to_repo(file_name,file_content):
    # Do the push..
```

file_name has the 1.json or any other file name as string and file_content has contents as string imported through json.dumps() by me in main function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Though I didn't found any ways to do it without cloning the repo in local directory**

*However, here's the way if you wanted to do while using a local directory:*

Function for cloning the private repo to local directory. You will also need to create a Personal Access Token([you can create here](https://github.com/settings/tokens)) and make sure to give repo permissions for cloning and making changes to the private repo.

```
def initialize_repo():
    os.system("git config --global user.name \"your.username\"")
    os.system("git config --global user.email \"your_github_email_here\"")
    os.system(r"git clone https://username:token@github.com/username/repo.git folder-name")
```

Function for pulling the repo:

```
def pull_repo():
    os.system(r"cd /app/folder-name/ && git pull origin master")
    return
```

Function for pushing the repo:

```
def push(pull="no"):
    PATH_OF_GIT_REPO = r'/app/folder-name/.git'  # make sure .git folder is properly configured
    COMMIT_MESSAGE = 'commit done by python script'
    # try:
    repo = Repo(PATH_OF_GIT_REPO)
    if pull=="yes":
        pull_repo()
    repo.git.add(update=True)
    repo.index.commit(COMMIT_MESSAGE)
    origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
    origin.push()
    # except:
    #     print('Some error occured while pushing the code')    
    return
```

**Now using these functions, just make a pull, then make the changes to the json or any other file you want and then do the push** :)